# Ensure all rsnapshot folders from all VMs in a Xen host are successfully backupped via rsync

Tags: lvm, backup, rsnapshot

On my Xen Host I first create an up-to-date snapshot of all VMs and then I use `rsnapshot` to backup all my important folders daily.

Secondly I backup the same folders on an external server via `rsync`

how can I ensure all those folders are successfully backed up on the external server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I do the external backup, I create a definition file `/root/folders_to_backup_external` in each VM and a cronjob in each VM to create a hidden file `.backupped_folder` that contains the current date in all folders, that are defined in `rsnapshot` with

```
# create hidden files with date to check in external server
19 2    * * *   root    for f in $(cat /root/folders_to_backup_external); do date +"%m-%d-%y %T">"$f".backupped_folder; done
```

In the end I can check every day on the external server if all those folders are up-to-date with

```
for f in $(locate .backupped_folder); do echo -n "$f - "; cat "$f"; done
```

Comment: `for f in $(locate ...)` is very inefficient.  and the file's timestamp contains the date. 
 you could use `find /path -type f -name .backupped_folder -ls`. Or, for more control over the output format, replace the `-ls` with `-printf '%p - %CY-%Cm-%Cd %Cr\n'`.   You can even use find's `-mtime` option to list the .backupped_folder files which are older than, say, the last known backup.